# How do I define a macro with multiple pragmas for Clang?

Tags: macros, clang, pragma

I'd like to add some macros to ease (un)setting a specific warning around routines that we are deprecating internally.

I'd like to turn this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

void Foo() __attribute__((deprecated("Warning: deprecated routine")))

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

into this:

```
MY_DEPRECATED_BEGIN

void Foo() MY_DEPRECATED

MY_DEPRECATED_END
```

The `MY_DEPRECATED_BEGIN` macro is giving me trouble as I have to specify *two* pragmas in a single macro. Can this be done?

(Bonus points for a solution that achieves the same effect using only the MY_DEPRECATED macro!)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
void Foo() __attribute__((deprecated));

#define MY_DEPRECATED_BEGIN \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic warning \"-Wdeprecated-declarations\"")


int main()
{
MY_DEPRECATED_BEGIN
    Foo();
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

The short answer to your technical question is that C99 provides the `_Pragma("foo")` construct, which is equivalent to `#pragma foo` but is processed slightly later, and doesn't need to be on a line by itself.

Your other problem is that `-Wdeprecated-declarations` doesn't do what you think it does. Simply *declaring* a function as deprecated will never give you a diagnostic, because `__attribute__((deprecated))` is *supposed* to be used (generally in header files). What causes the diagnostic is if you *use* a deprecated function — and it's at *that* point that the setting of `-Wdeprecated` becomes relevant.

If you really just want to deprecate `Foo` iff `MY_DEPRECATED` is set, then the right way to do *that* is

```
#ifdef MY_DEPRECATED
 #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
#else
 #define ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED
#endif

void Foo() ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this solution:

```
#define NS_SUPPRESS_DIRECT_USE(expr)   _Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
                                       _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wdeprecated-declarations\"")\
                                       expr\
                                       _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")
```

Then just add it:

```
NS_SUPPRESS_DIRECT_USE(
                      Foo();
                      );
```

Comment: That won't work if `expr` contains commas. You could use a variadic macro (C++11 or later) to avoid that problem.